# Does one have to confirm a critical hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, critical-hit

In D&D 3.5, one scored a critical threat, and then had to confirm the crit by hitting the monster's armor class again. In D&D 5th edition, it does not explicitly state that crits have to be confirmed (to my knowledge). Thus I have been operating under the assumption that crits do not have to be confirmed. Can anyone provide insight into this matter?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Correct, **critical hits do not have to be confirmed.** Any 20 on an attack die is a critical hit. (Fighters of the Champion archetype eventually score critical hits on rolls of 19, and then 18, also.)

> **Rolling a 1 or 20**
> ...If the d20 roll for an attack is a 20, the attack hits regardless of any modifiers or the target's AC. In addition, the attack is a critical hit. (PHB p194)
>
> **Critical Hits**
> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll extra dice for the attack's damage.... (PHB p.196)